# getting user input and store in database (python)

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to write a script which will accept inputs from user and that will be stored in the SQL server database.
But i don't know the appropriate method to do that. I have tried this but it is not working and throwing an error.

Also i want to take date input, how to do that.

```
    import pyodbc
    from datetime import datetime

 class data:
           def __init__(self):
                   self.name=raw_input( "Enter Name: ")
                   self.section=raw_input( "Enter section: ")
    ##               eon=raw_input( "Enter date : ")
    ##               feon=datetime.strptime( eon,'%Y, %m, %d')

    a=data()
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=KIRAN-PC;DATABASE=testing')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (a.name,a.section,'2013-01-01')")
    cnxn.commit()
```

Output:

```
Enter Name: adam
Enter section: A

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/data1", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (a.name,a.section,'2013-01-01')")
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "a.name" could not be bound. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "a.section" could not be bound. (4104)')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you use question marks whilst using parameters. You might use it like this:

```
cursor.execute("Insert into Students (Name,Section,Enrol_On) Values (?,?,"2013-01-01")",(a.name,a.section))
```

**EDIT:** You should check [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Inserting_Data) for a simple example about inserting data.